# Debug problems of ssh tunnel to remote mysql connection

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am running on my VPS `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` and locally `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` and I want to create a ssh-tunnel to connect to my database to run `SELECT`'s for reporting in my `laravel 6` application.

My production database has the following version:

```
> mysqld --version
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

And I connect with the following credentials from my local to my remote server:

```
DB_HOST_PROD=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_PROD=13306
DB_DATABASE_PROD=test_db
DB_USERNAME_PROD=root
DB_PASSWORD_PROD=prod_pwd
```

The mysql-server on prod is clearly running:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nbg1-1:~# netstat -tlpn | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      457519/mysqld       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      457519/mysqld
```

I have the following configuration for VARIABLES, when running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time%';` I get:

```
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
connect_timeout 90
default_password_lifetime   0
delayed_insert_timeout  300
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
flush_time  0
have_statement_timeout  YES
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout 300
lc_time_names   en_US
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
log_timestamps  UTC
long_query_time 10.000000
max_execution_time  0
mysqlx_connect_timeout  30
mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout   60
mysqlx_interactive_timeout  28800
mysqlx_port_open_timeout    0
mysqlx_read_timeout 30
mysqlx_wait_timeout 28800
mysqlx_write_timeout    60
net_read_timeout    90
net_write_timeout   90
original_commit_timestamp   36028797018963968
regexp_time_limit   32
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
slave_net_timeout   60
slow_launch_time    2
system_time_zone    CET
time_zone   SYSTEM
timestamp   1614522618.931326
wait_timeout    300
```

My firewall rules look like the following:

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-nbg1-1:~# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
127.0.0.1 3306/tcp         ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1                 
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

When running my `ssh-command` I get:

```
admin@admin-VirtualBox:~$ /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -v -v -v -N -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 -p 22 root@xx.xx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xx.xx.xxx.xxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx [xx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xx.xxx.xxx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:aaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xx.xxx.xxx
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55f736df0320), explicit, agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xx.xx.xxx.xxx ([xx.xx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:13306 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:3306
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 5 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 13306.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 13306.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Connection to port 13306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: read<=0 rfd 7 len 0
debug2: channel 2: read failed
debug2: channel 2: close_read
debug2: channel 2: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 2: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug1: Connection to port 13306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug2: fd 8 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34636 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34636 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd 7/7 cc -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34640 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t4 r1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)

debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 3: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 3: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 3: obuf empty
debug2: channel 3: close_write
debug2: channel 3: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 3: read<=0 rfd 8 len 0
debug2: channel 3: read failed
debug2: channel 3: close_read
debug2: channel 3: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 3: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 3: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 3: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 3: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug3: channel 3: will not send data after close
debug1: Connection to port 13306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: channel 3: will not send data after close
debug3: channel 3: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 3: rcvd close
debug3: channel 3: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 3: is dead
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34640 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34654 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 7/7 cc -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34640 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t4 r1 i3/0 o3/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)

debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
debug1: Connection to port 13306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug2: fd 8 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug2: channel 2: read<=0 rfd 7 len 0
debug2: channel 2: read failed
debug2: channel 2: close_read
debug2: channel 2: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 2: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34654 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34654 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd 7/7 cc -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34658 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t4 r1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)

admindebug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 3: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 3: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 3: obuf empty
debug2: channel 3: close_write
debug2: channel 3: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 3: read<=0 rfd 8 len 0
debug2: channel 3: read failed
debug2: channel 3: close_read
debug2: channel 3: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 3: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 3: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 3: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 3: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug3: channel 3: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 3: rcvd close
debug3: channel 3: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 3: is dead
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34658 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 13306 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34658 to 127.0.0.1 port 13306 (t4 r1 i3/0 o3/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)
```

The error I get in my application is that `MySQL server has gone away`.

It seems that the ssh tunnel is properly created, however it also seems that the data cannot be queried and provided via the tunnel. However, I am unsure if it is the firewall or a mysql use authorization issue or ...?

To be honest I have no idea how to further narrowing the problem space or how to debug further to find the real problem.

I really appreciate your reply!

**UPDATE**

My `max_allowed_package` value is:

[image]

With ssh-connection:

```
06:51:51.655444 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43736: Flags [S.], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0x592c), seq 2018907411, ack 4184943146, win 65483, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2011647773 ecr 2011647773,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 3cba 7f00 0001  E..<..@.@.<.....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0cea aad8 7856 1513 f971 2a2a  ........xV...q**
    0x0020:  a012 ffcb fe30 0000 0204 ffd7 0402 080a  .....0..........
    0x0030:  77e7 4f1d 77e7 4f1d 0103 0307            w.O.w.O.....
06:51:51.655453 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31733, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.43736 > localhost.mysql: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x7fe8), ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647773 ecr 2011647773], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 7bf5 4000 4006 c0cc 7f00 0001  E..4{.@.@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 aad8 0cea f971 2a2a 7856 1514  .........q**xV..
    0x0020:  8010 0200 fe28 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4f1d  .....(......w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4f1d                                w.O.
06:51:51.656318 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12050, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 147)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43736: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe87 (incorrect -> 0x2228), seq 1:96, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647774 ecr 2011647773], length 95
    0x0000:  4500 0093 2f12 4000 4006 0d51 7f00 0001  E.../.@.@..Q....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0cea aad8 7856 1514 f971 2a2a  ........xV...q**
    0x0020:  8018 0200 fe87 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4f1e  ............w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4f1d 5b00 0000 0a38 2e30 2e32 332d  w.O.[....8.0.23-
    0x0040:  3075 6275 6e74 7530 2e32 302e 3034 2e31  0ubuntu0.20.04.1
    0x0050:  00db 0000 0033 5877 6149 534d 3900 ffff  .....3XwaISM9...
    0x0060:  ff02 00ff cf15 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0070:  7f0a 5e34 754c 607e 461e 256b 0063 6163  ..^4uL`~F.%k.cac
    0x0080:  6869 6e67 5f73 6861 325f 7061 7373 776f  hing_sha2_passwo
    0x0090:  7264 00                                  rd.
06:51:51.656328 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31734, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.43736 > localhost.mysql: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x7f87), ack 96, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647774 ecr 2011647774], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 7bf6 4000 4006 c0cb 7f00 0001  E..4{.@.@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 aad8 0cea f971 2a2a 7856 1573  .........q**xV.s
    0x0020:  8010 0200 fe28 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4f1e  .....(......w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4f1e                                w.O.
06:51:51.852161 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31735, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 221)
    localhost.43736 > localhost.mysql: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfed1 (incorrect -> 0xc68f), seq 1:170, ack 96, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647970 ecr 2011647774], length 169
    0x0000:  4500 00dd 7bf7 4000 4006 c021 7f00 0001  E...{.@.@..!....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 aad8 0cea f971 2a2a 7856 1573  .........q**xV.s
    0x0020:  8018 0200 fed1 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4fe2  ............w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4f1e a500 0001 8da2 1a00 0000 00c0  w.O.............
    0x0040:  ff00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0050:  0000 0000 0000 0000 726f 6f74 0020 86df  ........root....
    0x0060:  8b4f b2fc 1fe6 bbae 2f0a c238 9ffe 3f26  .O....../..8..?&
    0x0070:  09b2 d41c 58ff 8b85 dc7b 2110 b909 6465  ....X....{!...te
    0x0080:  6d6f 5f6c 6172 6176 656c 5f6e 6c67 5f67  st.db.cachin
    0x00a0:  675f 7368 6132 5f70 6173 7377 6f72 6400  g_sha2_password.
    0x00b0:  2c0c 5f63 6c69 656e 745f 6e61 6d65 076d  ,._client_name.m
    0x00c0:  7973 716c 6e64 0c5f 7365 7276 6572 5f68  ysqlnd._server_h
    0x00d0:  6f73 7409 3132 372e 302e 302e 31         ost.127.0.0.1
06:51:51.852170 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12051, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43736: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x7d57), ack 170, win 511, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647970 ecr 2011647970], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 2f13 4000 4006 0daf 7f00 0001  E..4/.@.@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0cea aad8 7856 1573 f971 2ad3  ........xV.s.q*.
    0x0020:  8010 01ff fe28 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4fe2  .....(......w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4fe2                                w.O.
06:51:51.852292 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12052, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43736: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe58 (incorrect -> 0x310d), seq 96:144, ack 170, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647970 ecr 2011647970], length 48
    0x0000:  4500 0064 2f14 4000 4006 0d7e 7f00 0001  E..d/.@.@..~....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0cea aad8 7856 1573 f971 2ad3  ........xV.s.q*.
    0x0020:  8018 0200 fe58 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4fe2  .....X......w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4fe2 2c00 0002 fe6d 7973 716c 5f6e  w.O.,....mysql_n
    0x0040:  6174 6976 655f 7061 7373 776f 7264 0033  ative_password.3
    0x0050:  5877 6149 534d 397f 0a5e 3475 4c60 7e46  sds32d9..^32L`~F
    0x0060:  1e25 6b00                                .%k.
06:51:51.852298 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31736, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.43736 > localhost.mysql: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x7d26), ack 144, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011647970 ecr 2011647970], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 7bf8 4000 4006 c0c9 7f00 0001  E..4{.@.@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 aad8 0cea f971 2ad3 7856 15a3  .........q*.xV..
    0x0020:  8010 0200 fe28 0000 0101 080a 77e7 4fe2  .....(......w.O.
    0x0030:  77e7 4fe2   
...
```

Without ssh-connection:

```
06:42:53.613568 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6317, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1725)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43656: Flags [P.], cksum 0x04b2 (incorrect -> 0xcfa4), seq 4156521934:4156523607, ack 1523925399, win 6148, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011109731 ecr 2011097903], length 1673
06:42:53.613825 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 35946, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 61)
    localhost.43656 > localhost.mysql: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe31 (incorrect -> 0xeb37), seq 1:10, ack 1673, win 24565, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011109731 ecr 2011109731], length 9
06:42:53.613842 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6318, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43656: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x6e32), ack 10, win 6148, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011109731 ecr 2011109731], length 0
06:42:53.614497 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 35947, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 111)
    localhost.43656 > localhost.mysql: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe63 (incorrect -> 0xbd7a), seq 10:69, ack 1673, win 24565, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011109732 ecr 2011109731], length 59
06:42:53.614503 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6319, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43656: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x6df5), ack 69, win 6148, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011109732 ecr 2011109732], length 0
06:42:53.626323 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6320, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 532)
    localhost.mysql > localhost.43656: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0009 (incorrect -> 0x434c), seq 1673:2153, ack 69, win 6148, options [nop,nop,TS val 2011109744 ecr 2011109732], length 480
...
```

TO be honest I am not quite sure what to look for in these outputs as I get thousands of packages.

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: To narrow it down, lots of tips regarding config and logging are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away. Also ask yourself if the application is doing the same thing with and without tunnel. Finally, trace traffic on server e.g. `tcpdump -i lo -xX -v port 3306`.

Comment: @berndbausch Thx a lot for your reply! I updated my answer as I tried to do everything that you linked in your post. I am still not clear how to find the real problem for this issue. Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't see `max_allowed_packets` in your MySQL configuration though. Almost everybody recommends a very high value for this setting. What's the result of `tcpdump`, with tunnel and without tunnel?

Comment: @berndbausch Thx for your reply! I updated my question.